# gcloud app deploy behavior differs with/without bucket specified

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

A colleague and I have a bucket each in the same gcloud project, and are both experiencing this behavior on our respective buckets.

When I login to gcloud in local terminal and do `gcloud app deploy` without specifying anything, my code deploys to my bucket. If instead I do `gcloud app deploy --bucket=(my bucket)` a large number of files are deposited in the bucket whose names are long strings of alphanumerics. The files I want to put are compiled JS in a `build` folder, and these weird files seem to be all the individual JS files from the project instead. In both cases it finds the bucket fine but the first option concerns me because I worry it's only finding my bucket due to my account's permissions or something.

I'd appreciate any details anyone has on how `app deploy` really works because we're very confused about this. The first option appears to work but this won't do for automation and we don't want to deploy to all the buckets by accident and break everything.

Answer (score 2):

`gcloud app deploy` uses Google Cloud Storage buckets to stage files and potentially create containers that are used by the App Engine service:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#--bucket

If you don't specify a bucket using `--bucket` flag, defaults are used:

- `staging.[project-id].appspot.com`
- `[us.]artifacts.[project-id].appspot.com`

BLOBs are stored in a GCS bucket named:

- `[project-id].appspot.com`

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#activating_a_cloud_storage_bucket

**NB** If you also use Google Container Registry you may see additional buckets named `*.artifacts.[project-id].appspot.com`. As with the bucket used by App Engine these contain objects representing the container layers.